# R Studio - data in Global Environment automatically loads on startup - how to remove

Tags: r

When exiting R Studio, I'm usually prompted to `Save workspace image to ~/.RData`. I accidentally clicked `Save` at some point, and now my Global Environment automatically loads several functions and datasets when I open R Studio. I now have to clear all objects from the workspace when I startup R Studio.

How do I remove the data (or setting) that automatically loads the saved data so that the data is not loaded on startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It told you the filename.  Just delete that file, i.e. `~/.RData`.

And you can set the default in RStudio not to restore the workspace:  it's in `Tools | Global options | General | Restore .RData into workspace at startup.`  There's another option to say not to store it.